# Is there a way to disable cookies in your HTML/PHP Code for Logins

Tags: php, html, cookies, authentication

total Web Dev noob here, but I've been working on a website that involves logging in- The user puts his/her username and password. That's all fine and dandy, but the way that cookies work here can be a bit of a pain-Everytime I enter something in the text box, log in, and then go back to the log in page, whenever i want to type something in the login text box, there is a drop down menu for usernames and it can be really annoying- is there a way to prevent this in the actual code?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not within the cookie but with the browsers autocomplete feature.

If you want to disable it you should look to this answer: [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: Ah nice I did not know you could disable said behavior. Informative!

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown menu you are referring to is due to your browser, not the cookies your website may or may not be using. You can usually find the option to delete saved form history somewhere in your browser options near where you would clear your history.